# Sum lines in linux with different numbers but with the same pattern

Tags: linux, sum

I would like to know if is possible to sum in linux directly the following lines contained in one file.

```
34 cars 
13 cars 
11 drivers 
42 drivers
```

The output I would like to be

```
47 cars
53 drivers
```

Thank you!

I've searched the website but I didn't find something similar with my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' file
```

**UPD.** If the pattern consists of several words, then try

```
awk '{n=$1;$1="";a[$0]+=n}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' file
```

However, there are still issues with non-normalized white space, e.g. `a space` and `a  space` are the same pattern.

Comment: That's awesome ! thank you !  How should we do in case we have more than one word? let's say instead of "cars" we have "used cars" ?

Comment: if I would like to ignore case sensitive lines, where should I add BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} ?

Comment: Solved: You can see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562283/using-awk-ignore-casesensitve-pattern-when-summarize-lines-based-on-the-same-pa/31562418?noredirect=1#comment51081537_31562418

Comment: I was afk that time. I know `tolower()` function and you needn't have asked a separate question. I'd recommend to describe the problem in complete detail in a single question to avoid "ping-pong" format next time.