# Using awk, ignore casesensitve pattern when summarize lines based on the same pattern

Tags: awk, case-insensitive, counting

Using awk, I would like to ignore case sensitve pattern when summarize lines based on the same pattern.

I have the following line (big thanks to Andrey (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476320/andrey)

```
awk '{n=$1;$1="";a[$0]+=n}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' testing.txt
```

The file contents:

```
1 Used cars
12 Drivers
1 used cars
1 used  cars
14 drivers
2 Used Cars
```

the actual output is

```
2  Used Cars
14  drivers
12  Drivers
2  used cars
1  Used cars
```

What I need to have:

```
26 drivers/Drivers (doesn't matter)
5 used cars/Used Cars (doesn't matter)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the easiest way:

```
awk  '{$0=tolower($0);n=$1;$1="";a[$0]+=n}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' file
```

Comment: Thank you, Kent! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From [AWK Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html)

> One way to perform a case-insensitive match at a particular point in the program is to convert the data to a single case, using the tolower() or toupper() built-in string functions (which we haven’t discussed yet; see String Functions). For example:

`tolower($1) ~ /foo/  { … }`

> Another method, specific to gawk, is to set the variable IGNORECASE to a nonzero value (see Built-in Variables). When IGNORECASE is not zero, all regexp and string operations ignore case.

Also note: In awk $1 is the first coloumn, $2 the second... $0 is the whole line. (You don't want to index the array with the whole line)

This is what works on my machine:

`awk '{a[tolower($2) " " tolower($3)]+=$1;}END{for(i in a){print a[i], i}}' testing.txt`

output:

```
5 used cars
26 drivers
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, it's not working (none of your examples). ...the output is the same.

Comment: sorry for that, I mentioned it myself and provided a working version in the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much ! this is what I need !